# 32 bit software RAM utilization in a 64 bit windows machine

Tags: windows, laptop, memory, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have a 64-bit laptop with 8 Gb of ram, which came installed with a 32-bit MS Excel. So I wanted to know if MS Excel can utilize the complete ram, or is it just utilizing up to 4 Gb of Ram?

Comment: No; 32-but Excel cannot use more than 4GB. If you need excel to have access to more memory reinstall Office and use the 64-bit installer

Answer (score 1):

4GB-system usage, if the app is large address aware, otherwise 2GB.

See [Stack Overflow - How much memory can a 32 bit process access on a 64 bit operating system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639540/how-much-memory-can-a-32-bit-process-access-on-a-64-bit-operating-system) for more detail.